# kafka connector HTTP/API source

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am actually aware on how to capture data from any data source, such as a specific API (e.g HTTP GET request) and ingest them in specific kafka connector.

```
{
    "name": "localfileSource", 
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "FileStreamSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "file": "test.txt",
        "topic": "connectSource"
    }
}
```

I would need something similar to this(`FileStreamSourceConnector`), that can be used with API sources.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a bit late for the question asker, but I had a similar need and I decided to implement my own connector.

The particularity of the connector is that it implements some sort of [Change Data Capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture)

In case it can help anyone else, you can find it here: [castorm/kafka-connect-http](https://github.com/castorm/kafka-connect-http)

Answer (score 1):

You can always build your own connectors, to stream from http source in a set of intervals is relatively simple.

I am aware that you may have solved your problems, a naive implementation can be found:
https://github.com/pegerto/kafka-connect-http

Regards.