# kafka connect for openweathermap

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

we have all the available connector listed here : https://www.confluent.io/hub/

Can anyone please suggest me which one I can use for fech data from openweathermap api.

There is a connector for twitter but not for a URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kafka connector HTTP/API source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568940/kafka-connector-http-api-source)

Comment: no it doesn't .

Comment: And why not? The connector answered there pulls any HTTP endpoint after an amount of time.